# How to get the selected file path in OpenFileDialog which belongs to other apps?

Tags: c++, windows, api

Is it possible? Does it require COM knowledge?

The pic shows a OpenFileDialog from VS2013, I want my app to get current selected path in that OpenFileDialog.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is your **real** problem?

Comment: What to you mean by belongs to other apps? Are you just trying to get the selected file from OpenFileDialog?

Comment: The pic shows a OpenFileDialog from VS2013, I want my app to get current selected path in that OpenFileDialog.

Comment: Why, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx) or [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) or [Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx) for doing this. Here is the algorithm:

1. Find the Automation element for the path (exists at the top of the dialog, below the title).
2. The Name property will give you the full path selected
3. Find the Automation element for the file name selected
4. The text property of the above automation element will give you the filename.

Concatenate both and you get the full file path.

Comment: Wow, looks not easy. Thanks. I will try on it

Comment: Of course, this leaves the big question: WHEN do you do this? The selection may exist for **literally** a few milliseconds.

Comment: Before March, I guess.

Comment: I tried to implement it today. The limitation of this is that the file name has to be full name, if it doesn't displayed with a suffix, it will fail.